# How to avoid multiple if statements where result is add to list

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I would like to ask you for an idea. I have class, where I have a lot of if statements, lets say it looks like that:

```
List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
boolean errorCodition1 = SuperUtils.calculateIfObjectIsCorrect(this); // rest of them same

if(errorCondition1){
    errors.add(errorsMessage.getSuperError());
}

if(errorCondition2){
    errors.add(errorsMessage.getMinorError());
}

if(errorCondition3){
    errors.add(errorsMessage.getAlmostCriticalError());
}

if(errorCondition4){
    errors.add(errorsMessage.getOverNineThousendError());
}

displayErrors(errors);
```

Maybe this code does not look super terrible, but lets assume that we will need to add more conditions. How would you avoid it?

This code is called always when class is initialize, so lets say for example in constructor.

Comment: Is `errorCondition1` really an identifier (of probably a bool variable)? Or is that pseudo code for a boolean expression? If the former I could imagine improvements. Otherwise not.

Comment: `errorCondition1` is bool, which is calculated before this pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using java8 and later, you can simplify this by extracting the if statements to a function:

```
void addToErrorsIf(boolean errorCondition, List<String> errors, Supplier<String> a) {
  if(errorCondition) {
    errors.add(a.get());
  }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
addToErrorsIf(errorCodition1, errors, errorsMessage::getSuperError);
addToErrorsIf(errorCodition2, errors, errorsMessage::getMinorError);
//and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map for such an case:

```
    // It would be grate to have a iterable collection of errorConditions
    final Boolean errorCondition1 = false;
    final Boolean errorCondition2 = true;
    final Boolean errorCondition3 = false;
    final Boolean errorCondition4 = true;
    final List<Boolean> errorConditions =  List.of(
            errorCondition1,
            errorCondition2,
            errorCondition3,
            errorCondition4
    );


    final List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    // The key generator function: f ( b:Bool, x:Int ) -> x if b == true else -1
    // -1 is the default case
    final BiFunction<Boolean, Integer, Integer> key = (condition, id) -> condition ? 
    id : -1;

    // The error handler
    final Map<Integer, Runnable> handler = new HashMap<>();

    // do nothing in the default case
    handler.put(-1, () -> {});

    // The errorID
    int errorID = 0;

    handler.put(errorID++, () -> errors.add(errorsMessage1.getSuperError()));
    handler.put(errorID++, () -> errors.add(errorsMessage2.getMinorError()));
    handler.put(errorID++, () -> errors.add(errorsMessage3.getAlmostCriticalError()));
    handler.put(errorID, () -> errors.add(errorsMessage3.getOverNineThousendError()));

    errorID = 0;

    // Iterate all conditions and execute the runnable´s if the conditions are true;
    for (final boolean errorCondition: errorConditions) {
        handler.get(key.apply(errorCondition, errorID)).run();
        errorID++;
    }

    displayErrors(errors);
```